# Nsubstitute mock method with any arguments is not working .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, nsubstitute

I'm trying to mock the method with `Arg.Any<T>()` parameter. The mocked method properly redirected on calling in .netframework and not in netcoreapp.

Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47647706/nsubstitute-mock-method-is-not-returning-expected-result) similar to this issue , but this issue seems to be NSubstitute is not working properly in net core.

And Github Link is [here](https://github.com/MathuMohanVA/Samples/blob/master/NSubstitute_Not_Working.zip)

**Note: Instead of passing Arg.Any value, passing the particular parameter value it works fine**

Compared in both netframework(4.5.1) and net core app(2.1) libraries.

**Dotnet Core result:**

```
Test Name:  ClassLibrary1.Class1.Method
Test FullName:  ClassLibrary1.Class1.Method
Test Source:    C:\Users\mmohan\source\repos\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\Class1.cs : line 10
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00.177

Result StackTrace:  at ClassLibrary1.Class1.Method() in C:\Users\mmohan\source\repos\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\Class1.cs:line 16
Result Message: 
Assert.Throws() Failure
Expected: typeof(System.FormatException)
Actual:   (No exception was thrown)
```

**Net framework result:**

```
Test Name:  ClassLibrary1.Class1.Method
Test FullName:  ClassLibrary1.Class1.Method
Test Source:    C:\Users\mmohan\source\repos\SampleTestIssue\ClassLibrary1\Class1.cs : line 10
Test Outcome:   Passed
Test Duration:  0:00:00.292
```

**My Code:**

```
using NSubstitute;
using System;
using Xunit;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Method()
        {
            IB b = Substitute.For<IB>();
            A a = new A(b);
            b.doSomeB(Arg.Any<string>()).Returns(x => { throw new FormatException("Something there"); });
            a.doSomeA("");
            Exception exception = Assert.Throws<FormatException>(
                () => b.doSomeB(Arg.Any<string>()));
        }
    }
    public class A
    {
        public IB _b;
        public A(IB b)
        {_b = b;}
        public void doSomeA(string aa)
        {
            try
            { _b.doSomeB("");}
            catch (Exception ex){ }         
        }
    }
    public class B : IB
    {
        public string doSomeB(string bb)
        {
            try{ }
            catch (Exception ex){ }
            return "";
        }
    }
    public interface IB
    {
        string doSomeB(string bb);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can post this to nsub github as an issue.

Answer (score 2):

The problem of inconsistent behavior is caused by wrong usage of argument matchers. In the last line of your test you do

```cs
Exception exception = Assert.Throws(
() => b.doSomeB(Arg.Any()));
```

so you use `Arg.Any` outside of NSubstitute "context" - meaning you didn't specify Returns, Throws or any other NSubstitute action which should be executed. Please take a look at documentation [here](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/argument-matchers/) and [here](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/argument-matchers/#how_not_to_use_argument_matchers). Long story short

> Argument matchers should only be used when specifying calls for the purposes of setting return values, checking received calls, or configuring callbacks (for example: with `Returns`, `Received` or `When`). Using `Arg.Is` or `Arg.Any` in other situations can cause your tests to behave in unexpected ways.

When you replace `Arg.Any` in `Assert.Throws` with actual value, the test will be green.